# Read/Write on USB, C#

Tags: c#, usb

I use [LibUsbDotNet](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html) to read data from USB with following code:

```
public static UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinder = new UsbDeviceFinder(Convert.ToInt32(0x046D), Convert.ToInt32(0xC06A));  
public static UsbDevice MyUsbDevice;  
MyUsbDevice = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(MyUsbFinder);
```

it doesn't work. can not find my USB device.
can you help me?!
you can download library and samples from [here](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html)

Comment: An int constant does not need to be converted; use `new UsbDeviceFinder(0x046D, 0xC06A)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the necessary drivers? The help file for LibUsbDotNet says:

> Before LibUsbDotNet can access a usb device on a Windows operating system the device must be installed with either WinUSB or libusb-win32 usb drivers.

Otherwise I can't see anything wrong with your code when compared to the examples.

---

As an aside your use of `Convert.ToInt32()` is redundant. This will do the same thing:

```
public static UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinder = new UsbDeviceFinder(0x046D, 0xC06A);
```

But that has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answers...  
My big problem is that I want to send data from one computer to another, no computer recognize the other computer as a USB device, therefore I can't install driver because there is no VID and PID for computer.
what i must to do?!

Comment: That won't work without a special cable. Search for a *USB to USB Transfer Cable*. Each computer will then recognize the cable itself as an USB device and you can use special software to transfer files. Getting such a cable to work in your own software is probably not easy.